# index.html not loading xampp tomcat server

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, servlets, xampp

I was trying to run a very simple servlet code that I have just learned but it looks like Tomcat is not being able to figure out where my index.html page is.

My directory structure:

[image]

My web.xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>First Java Servlet Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Add</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.firstjavaapp.AddServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Add</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have gone through most of the StackOverflow answers on this issue but none worked for me.
Every time it is showing 404.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The root of the web application is in the `WebContent` folder of your project, therefore you don't have an `/index.html` resource, just `/WEB-INF/index.html` (which will never be served directly by the server). Move the file to the `WebContent` folder and it should work.

Comment: the index.html file is in the WebContent folder only.